# React re-render after API call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm working on a simple React app alongside TypeScript, and I'm using JSONPlaceholder for API calls simulation. I have implemented everything I need, but facing a problem when it comes to re-rendering components that shows response data from API. The thing is that if I do HTTP GET to all data after I do DELETE or PUT, I will again get all same data because data changes don't actually apply on the server.
I will appreciate it if you can help me how to edit my functions for DELETE and PUT.

When I console.log my responses inside components, I get staus ok 200, so the API call part is fine, the only thing that I struggle with is how to re-render components properly

There is a component that shows all data, and also make calls to DELETE endpoint, and shows modal where I call PUT endpoint:

```
const PostsTable: React.FunctionComponent = () => {
  const [posts, setPosts] = useState<Array<IPost>>([]);
  const [selectedPost, setSelectedPost] = useState<IPost>({});
  const [dialogOpen, setDialogOpen] = useState<boolean>(false);

  const fetchPosts = () => {
    PostService.getAllPosts()
      .then((response: any) => {
        setPosts(response.data);
      })
      .catch((e: Error) => {
        console.log(e);
      });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchPosts();
  }, []);

  const editPost = (post: IPost) => (event: any) => {
    setSelectedPost(post);
    setDialogOpen(true);
  };

  const handleClose = () => {
    setDialogOpen(false);
  };

  const deletePost =
    (id: any): any =>
    (event: Event) => {
      event.stopPropagation();
      PostService.deletePost(id)
        .then((response: any) => {
          setPosts(posts);
          console.log(response);
        })
        .catch((e: Error) => {
          console.log(e);
        });
    };

  return (
    <Container fixed>
      {!posts || posts.length < 1 ? (
        <div style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
          <CircularProgress color="primary" size={100} />
        </div>
      ) : (
        <TableContainer component={Paper}>
          <Table sx={{ minWidth: 650 }} aria-label="simple table">
            <TableHead>
              <TableRow>
                <TableCell align="left">User Id</TableCell>
                <TableCell align="left">Post Id</TableCell>
                <TableCell align="left">Title</TableCell>
                <TableCell align="left">Actions</TableCell>
              </TableRow>
            </TableHead>
            <TableBody>
              {posts.map((post: IPost) => (
                <TableRow
                  key={post.id}
                  sx={{ '&:last-child td, &:last-child th': { border: 0 } }}
                >
                  <TableCell>{post.userId}</TableCell>
                  <TableCell align="left">{post.id}</TableCell>
                  <TableCell align="left">{post.title}</TableCell>
                  <TableCell align="left">
                    <Tooltip title="Delete">
                      <IconButton onClick={editPost(post)}>
                        <EditIcon />
                      </IconButton>
                    </Tooltip>
                    <Tooltip title="Edit">
                      <IconButton onClick={deletePost(post.id)}>
                        <DeleteIcon />
                      </IconButton>
                    </Tooltip>
                  </TableCell>
                </TableRow>
              ))}
            </TableBody>
          </Table>
        </TableContainer>
      )}
      {
        <EditPostDialog
          open={dialogOpen}
          handleClose={handleClose}
          selectedPost={selectedPost}
        />
      }
    </Container>
  );
};

export default PostsTable;
```

And also, there is a modal component with PUT function:

```
const EditPostDialog: React.FunctionComponent<IEditPostDialog> = (
  props: IEditPostDialog
) => {
  const { open, handleClose, selectedPost } = props;

  const [post, setPost] = useState<IPost>({});

  useEffect(() => {
    const newPost = {
      id: selectedPost.id,
      userId: selectedPost.userId,
      title: selectedPost.title,
      body: selectedPost.body,
    };
    setPost(newPost);
  }, [selectedPost]);

  const handleChange = (event: any) => {
    setPost({ ...post, [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
  };

  const handleSubmit = () => {
    PostService.updatePost(post.id, post)
      .then((response: any) => {
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch((e: Error) => {
        console.log(e);
      });
    handleClose();
  };

  return (
    <Dialog onClose={handleClose} open={open}>
      <DialogTitle id="simple-dialog-title">Post info</DialogTitle>
      <DialogContent classes={{ root: 'dialog-content' }}>
        <TextField
          id="userId"
          label="User Id"
          name="userId"
          variant="outlined"
          value={post.userId}
          onChange={handleChange}
          style={{ marginTop: 16 }}
        />
        <TextField
          id="title"
          label="Title"
          name="title"
          variant="outlined"
          value={post.title}
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
        <TextField
          id="body"
          label="Body"
          name="body"
          variant="outlined"
          value={post.body}
          onChange={handleChange}
          multiline
        />
      </DialogContent>
      <DialogActions>
        <Button onClick={handleClose}>Close</Button>
        <Button onClick={handleSubmit}>Submit</Button>
      </DialogActions>
    </Dialog>
  );
};

export default EditPostDialog;
```

And at the end, my PostService.ts and HTTP files where is axios code to call API points:

```
const getAllPosts = () => {
  return http.get<Array<IPost>>('/posts');
};

const getSinglePost = (id: number | undefined) => {
  return http.get<IPost>(`/posts/${id}`);
};

const createPost = (data: IPost) => {
  return http.post<IPost>('/posts', data);
};

const updatePost = (id: number | undefined, data: IPost) => {
  return http.put<any>(`/posts/${id}`, data);
};

const deletePost = (id: number | undefined) => {
  return http.delete<any>(`/posts/${id}`);
};

const PostService = {
  getAllPosts,
  getSinglePost,
  createPost,
  updatePost,
  deletePost,
};
```

```
export default axios.create({
  baseURL: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com',
  headers: {
    'Content-type': 'application/json',
  },
});
```

Thank you all guys :)

Answer (score 0):

Your delete function uses "setPosts(posts)" which I'm pretty sure is not what you meant. Also, your modal does not tell your main component that a post has been edited, I guess that's the problem ? Pass a callback to the modal to update the posts state in the main component.